# Trying to revive an old hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, macos

I had a few old backup drives from my Windows computer that I wanted to go through. They are 5-6 years old. And they are internal drives so I got a USB adapter kit from the brand Deltaco.

So far I haven't been able to get one of the drives to show up in Finder.

So my question is, if these drives haven't been broken by the years what is the best way to see if I can extract some info from them?

Is there any special extraction software I need or is it of no use if the drive can't be found in Finder?

Any other tips?

Appreciate all the help I can get in this matter!

Comment: Was the adaptor advertised to work with Mac?

Comment: Nope, it said windows actually. But the smaller disks that didn't needed electricity worked. But you might be right that this could be a problem. Luckily I think I have my old Windows computer somewhere so I can repeat the test. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's your adaptor's fault.  It's most likely not Mac friendly (aka no drivers).  Try out a Windows machine.

Comment: Have fun with it!

Answer (score 1):

Did you go into Disk Utility to detect the drives?  Normally they would show up there although they'll need to be formatted in a Mac Journaled format or Windows ExFat one.  If you cannot see them in Disk Utility you may need to connect them to a Windows machine and do a format there. Hopefully not necessary and Disk Utility will sort you out ;-)

Comment: I did go to Disk Utility and they didn't show there. But they are likely not formatted in Mac or ExFat but most likely in NTFS. That shouldn't be a problem though from what I heard.